# Some CSS classes missing when rendering the page with get_the_content()

Tags: block-editor, the-content

I am using `get_the_content()` to load other pages content on the current page, and I noticed some block CSS classes are missing in the HTML I get.

For example, `is-layout-flex` layout CSS class is missing for the Columns block, which is causing block to look different from how it looks when the page is open normally, in a browser tab.

When I open page normally, in a browser tab I get this: 
`<div class="is-layout-flex wp-container-7 wp-block-columns">`

But, when I get the content of the page with the get_the_content(), I get this: 
`<div class="wp-block-columns">`

Is there a way to make `get_the_content()` provide exactly the same content as it is provided when the page is open normally, in a browser tab?

Comment: Actually, why don't you just use `the_content()`? Why must `get_the_content()`? Because it will return the raw block HTML with the block comment delimiters like `<!-- wp:columns -->`.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer Sally, Honestly I was not quite sure about the difference between them. I could use `the_content()` as well.

Comment: In that case, then you should probably just use `the_content()`, unless if you don't want the filters like mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/#more-information) (and *many* other filters) to be applied, which also means you'd need to manually apply the `do_blocks()` to ensure blocks are parsed properly (e.g. specific CSS classes are added).

Comment: It should also be noted that **`get_the_content()` *returns* the content**, whereas `the_content()` *displays* (i.e. `echo`) the content. But `the_content()` is *not* simply a shorthand/wrapper for `echo get_the_content()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by applying the `the_content` filters, just like what [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) does:

```php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );

echo $content;
```

Or the other way is by applying [`do_blocks()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_blocks/) on the content:

```php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = do_blocks( $content );

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you! do_blocks() is what I need.